# Running an application as part of the ssh command

Tags: ssh

I've got a custom application which works fine when run directly from the command line in Ubuntu VM or over SSH if I type the commands myself in the prompt.

If I run the same application by connecting to the Ubuntu over SSH (from Windows machine) and sending the command as part of the ssh command, the SSH console doesn't print any output from the application. The application (effectively a TCP server) seems dead as I can't connect to it at that point.
However when I close the command prompt and effectively end the SSH session the application springs to life and I can connect to it, no problems!

When I run `who` in Ubuntu VM it doesn't list the SSH connection at all, but if I run `ss -t -a` I can see that the application is actually listening. Doing `ps` doesn't show the application running either.

Does it make any sense to anyone?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the exact commands you run directly and using SSH and add details about the "custom application". Show the `ps` command you use. The application might run in the background in a separate process group, and you might need additional options for `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

It seem I forgot a few things when constructing the command. This one works as intended:

```
ssh -t user@xx.xx.xx.xx "sudo ./xyz.sh; exec bash -l"
```